# Only use pictures taken through the camera, iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to write a function with which the user can take and upload upload a pic to my server. I want to disallow users from selecting a picture from the Photo Roll though. Is there anyway I can do this using the ImagePicker pod?

```
func cancelButtonDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController) {
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func wrapperDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
}

func doneButtonDidPress(imagePicker: ImagePickerController, images: [UIImage]) {
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func pictureButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    //take picture
    let imagePickerController = ImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.imageLimit = 1
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import DKImagePickerController


@IBAction func pictureButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()

        pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in
            let size = CGSizeMake(512, 512)
            assets[0].fetchImageWithSize(size, completeBlock: { image, info in
                self.image = image
                self.pictureButton.setBackgroundImage(self.image, forState: .Normal)
            })
        }

        pickerController.singleSelect = true
        pickerController.maxSelectableCount = 1
        pickerController.sourceType = .Camera

        self.presentViewController(pickerController, animated: true) {}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `sourceType` as `camera` to open image picker as camera only.

```
@IBAction func pictureButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let imagePickerController = ImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.imageLimit = 1
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    // Add these lines

    imagePickerController.sourceType = .camera

    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: sourceType was indeed what I was looking for but the framework I was using (ImagePicker) give compile errors with the code above. I decided to use DKImagePickerController instead and was able to make it work.